# PGF macro to map value to a different interval

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, random-numbers, hobby

I'm trying to write a macro to be used with random generators (in particular `rnd`) within Tikz, to map numbers to different intervals.

```
[0, 1] ---> [a, b]
f(x) = x*(b-a) + a
```

What I tried so far is:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\newcommand{\interval}[3]{%
    \pgfmathparse{(#3-#2)*#1 + #2}
}
\newcommand{\showinterval}[3]{%
    \interval{#1}{#2}{#3}\pgfmathresult
}
\begin{document}
   \tikzset{
        potato/.pic = {
            \draw[use Hobby shortcut,closed]
            (0,0) .. (\showinterval{rnd}{0}{0.5},0.5) .. (1,0);
        }
}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0, 0) rectangle (1, 1);    
        \draw (0,0) pic[scale=0.1] {potato};
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

But I get an error `Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored` that seems related to non-expandability of pgf macros. In theory the `\showinterval` macro was made to avoid this issue.

Where's the flaw?

Comment: If you simply use a `declare function` then you don't need any of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't check exactly the location where it trips up but this is usually the case with TikZ parser that if you throw unchewed macro that involves its own machinery it gets stuck often.

Here is another alternative via defining a proper math function using `declare function`

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
potato/.pic = {\draw[use Hobby shortcut,closed] (0,0) 
                     .. ({intervalmap(0,0.5,rnd)},0.5) .. (1,0);},
declare function={intervalmap(\a,\b,\s) = \s*(\b - \a) + \a;}
]
\draw (0, 0) rectangle (1, 1);
\draw (0,0) pic[scale=.1] {potato};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way to go is to work with `\pgfextra`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\newcommand{\myinterval}[3]{%
    \pgfmathparse{(#3-#2)*#1 + #2}
    \xdef\myx{\pgfmathresult}
}

\begin{document}
   \tikzset{
        potato/.pic = {
            \draw[use Hobby shortcut,closed]
            \pgfextra{\myinterval{rnd}{0}{0.5}}
            (0,0) .. (\myx,0.5) .. (1,0);
        }
}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0, 0) rectangle (1, 1);    
        \draw (0,0) pic[scale=0.1] {potato};
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```